# Constructing Sequences in Lp

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

[image][image][image]Consider Banach Space $L^{p}(U)$ where $U$ is bounded open subset in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Take a bounded sequence $\{u_{m}\}_{m}^{\infty}$ in $L^{p}(U)$. Consider a subsequence $\{u_{m_{j}}\}_{j}^{\infty} \subset \{u_{m}\}_{m}^{\infty}$ such that $\text{limsup}_{j,k \rightarrow \infty}||u_{m_{j}}-u_{m_{k}}||_{L^{p}(U)} \leq \delta$.

What is the standard diagonal argument to extract a subsequence $\{u_{m_{l}}\}_{l}^{\infty} \subset \{u_{m}\}_{m}^{\infty}$ satisfying:

$\text{limsup}_{j,k \rightarrow \infty}||u_{m_{j}}-u_{m_{k}}||_{L^{p}(U)} = 0$

with $\delta = 1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...$

Thanks!

Comment: First, you have to assume that such a subsequence exists. Boundedness alone does not imply that.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake, $U$ is bounded open subset.

Comment: @Daniel the first limsup inequality I already have proved, so it can be used for the contruction.

Comment: Have you anything that guarantees that you can extract further subsequences that become Cauchy? In other words, have you anything that guarantees that $(u_m)$ has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Yes I have that $\{u_{m}^{\epsilon}\}_{m}$ is uniformly bounded and uniformly equicontinuous and so by Ascoli-Arzela there exists a convergent subsequence on compact subsets. Where $u^{\epsilon} = \eta_{\epsilon}\ast u_{m}$. Not sure if that helps. It says that the first limsup argument is used with a standard diagonal argument.

Comment: I have added images of the full compactness proof, but my question is on the last part.(part 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a sequence that is not only bounded in $L^p(U)$, you have a sequence that is bounded in $W^{1,p}(U)$. That is an important difference, since that also gives bounds for the (weak) derivatives, and the long first part of the proof establishes that under these conditions, you can, for every $\delta > 0$, extract a subsequence such that

$$\limsup_{j,k\to\infty} \lVert u_{m_j} - u_{m_k}\rVert_{L^q(U)} \leqslant \delta.$$

Now we come to the standard diagonal sequence construction. Note that a subsequence of a sequence $x_m$ corresponds to a strictly increasing function $\sigma \colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, per $x_{m_k} = x_{\sigma(k)}$.

So extracting the first subsequence for $\delta = 1$ produces a sequence

$$u_{m_k} = u_{\sigma_1(k)} = u_{1,k}$$

of the original sequence with $\limsup\limits_{j,k\to\infty} \lVert u_{1,j} - u_{1,k}\rVert \leqslant 1$. Now the sequence $(u_{1,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is of course bounded in $W^{1,p}(U)$, so satisfies the same assumptions, and hence by the long argument before, we can extract a subsequence

$$u_{2,k} = u_{1,\sigma_2(k)} = u_{\sigma_1(\sigma_2(k))}$$

of $u_{1,k}$ with $\limsup\limits_{j,k\to\infty} \lVert u_{2,j}-u_{2,k}\rVert \leqslant \frac12$. That is still a subsequence of the original (of course), hence staisfies the assumptions, and we can extract a further subsequence... Recursively, for every $m\in \mathbb{N}$, we can extract a subsequence $(u_{m+1,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ of $(u_{m,k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $\limsup\limits_{j,k\to\infty} \lVert u_{m+1,j} - u_{m+1,k}\rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{m+1}$.

Since in general you must expect that $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \sigma_1(\dotsc(\sigma_m(k))\dotsc) = \infty$ for some $k$, you can't take the "limit" of these subsequences, therefore you take the diagonal sequence

$$v_k = u_{k,k} = u_{\sigma_1(\dotsc(\sigma_k(k))\dotsc)},$$

which is a subsequence of the original, and since $(v_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is - except possibly for the first $m$ terms - a subsequence of $(u_{m,k})$, you have $\limsup\limits_{j,k\to\infty} \lVert v_j - v_k\rVert \leqslant \frac1m$ for every $m$, and that means that $(v_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence. By completeness of $L^q(U)$, it converges, so the original sequence contains a subsequence that converges in $L^q$.